Getting solution in non-convex optimization problem by using KKT condition
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{maximize}&-\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1} W_{ij}^2\
&\operatorname{s.t}&\sum_{i}^n\sum_{j}^n\sum_{j'}^n(W_{ij}-W_{ij'})^2\leq c\
& & 0\leq W_{ij} \leq 1 \quad \forall j\
& & W_{ii} = 0
\end{align}
The above are the optimization problem.
Please help me to find optimal solution by using KKT condition
